# I am eager to know details about distribution of bitcoin

Tags: learning

Bitcoin only has 21 million possible coins so far I know. Who hold these coins? I just want rough estimation.

Comment: related: [Is there a reliable way to measure Bitcoin wealth distribution?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/3461/5406)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Steven Englander: Best estimates are that there are about one million holders of Bitcoin;  47 individuals hold about 30 percent, another 900 hold a further 20 percent, the next 10,000 about 25% and another million about 20%, with 5% being lost.

Read more: http://www.businessinsider.com/bitcoin-inequality-2014-1#ixzz2rEi2kG5g