# Are there estimates on the geographical distribution of the bitcoin supply?

Tags: money-supply

There are two similar question on the site:

1. [Is there data on the geographic distribution of bitcoin users?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/696/4276)
2. [I am eager to know details about distribution of bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/21020/4276)

The first is asking where the users of Bitcoin are located. The second is asking about percentage distributions among those users. Interesting data.

What I want to know is the geographic distribution of the bitcoins themselves. For example, what percentage of the bitcoin supply is held by North Americans (or North American companies)?

Comment: This can probably use better tags. I invite help with that.

Comment: The bitcoins themselves exist both everywhere (on the physical storage of everybody who is running a full Bitcoin client), and nowhere (since it's a virtual currency and coins don't physically exist). So your question really reduces to the same as [Is there data on the geographic distribution of bitcoin users?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/696/is-there-data-on-the-geographic-distribution-of-bitcoin-users).

Answer (score 2):

http://fiatleak.com/

This tool supposedly gets data from "Mt. Gox, Bitstamp and BTC China to show you which countries and which currencies are moving in and out of bitcoin in real time."  I'm assuming it's just Mt. Gox and Bitstamp now and possibly others.

-http://www.zerohedge.com/news/2013-11-11/meet-fiatleakcom-%E2%80%93-real-time-map-bitcoin-transactions-country

---

## UPDATE

As of September 2019, the exchanges from which the data seem to come are listed under "exchange" in the bottom left of the tool. Perhaps take it with a grain of salt, as there's some obvious errors, such as gdax still being listed along with coinbase pro. Gdax was rebranded as coinbase pro about two years ago. The listed exchanges are:

- bitfinex
- bitflyer
- bitmex
- bitstamp
- bittrex
- cex.io
- coinbase pro
- exmo
- gdax
- gemini
- itbit
- kraken
- livecoin
- neraex
- quoine
- yobit