# how to know miner of each bitcoin block

Tags: blockchain, api

Do you know from what kind of API I can get miner info per each block?

I've run bitcoin mainnet, and I want to know who mines each block if possbile.

I've googled and read many docs but I couldn't find out some helpful info.

Please help me if you know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine the geographic distribution of the hashrate?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/90306/how-to-determine-the-geographic-distribution-of-the-hashrate). The answer explains why it is not possible to determine with certainty which mining pool found the winning block.

Comment: @UgamKamat Thank you for your explanation :)